# How to pass session value which is an object to external JS file

Tags: javascript, razor

I have these variables defined in cshtml which are

```
'@{
    var myObject = (Session["myObject"] as Models.myObject);
}'
```

I want to use this myObject variable in external Javascript file. Is it possible

I tried adding it in Div tag of cshtml

```
id = sessionVar data-id ="Session["myObject"]
```

In external file:

```
var myObj=$('#sessionVar').attr('data-id');
```

But it returns "myObject" but not the Object value

Comment: So... What is your question?

Comment: I found a work around for this , I still am not able to get all the data in the object but if I point to only one value in the object it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not reach Asp.net object in external files. But if you want, you can pass Asp.net Object value to js externall func.

Like this

```
<script>
....
var myObjValue=@(string)Session["MyName"]
externalFunc(myObjValue)
......
</script>
```

You have to cast your Session value to certain type
I accept that this session type String and I showed above